# crontab permission denied when writing output to file

Tags: python, bash, permissions, cron

I would like to run my program and save the prints to a log file.
within the discordbot.py the text is printed to the command-line via logging.warnings()

```
@reboot python3 /home/pi/shared/discordbot.py & >/home/pi/shared/botlog.log 2>&1
```

Error I get:

```
-bash: /home/pi/shared/botlog.log: Permission denied
```

why does sudo crontab not have access to the log file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its self explanatory=>Permission denied. change permissions and then run your command again

Answer (score 0):

You must obey this structure:

```
chmod u+x discordbot.py
chmod u+w /home/pi/shared/botlog.log

python3 /home/pi/shared/discordbot.py 1>> /home/pi/shared/botlog.log 2>&1
```